# Sumar el total del mes que se genero

Tags: php

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
SUM(i.total) AS TOTAL, 
MONTHNAME(i.fecha) AS MES 
FROM 
impresiones i, usuarios u 
WHERE 
(u.usuario)='$idusuario' 
and (i.idempleado)=(u.idempleado) 
GROUP BY Mes
```

Quiero calcular el total de las impresiones que se realizaron durante el mes en la cual, probé esta consulta en mysql y este es mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaria que me ayudaran como puedo reflejar esos mismos datos en php.

Realmente soy nueva en esto, pido una disculpa si no me di a entender.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a mostrar esos resultados en una pagina en php?

Comment: Asi es quisiera que me arrojara esos mismos datos en mi pagina web.

Comment: has intentado algo para poder mostrar algun resultado?

Comment: Ya te puse una respuesta, me dices si te funciono o no

Comment: Si muchas gracias, lo acople a mi sistema y quedo, gracias!!

Comment: @ErikaRamirez de nada :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer esto `$db = mysqli_connect("host", "ususario", "contraseña", "database");` usando la funcion **mysqli_connect** te conectas a una base de datos y le pasas los parametros que te indica, y despues agregas esto

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT 
SUM(i.total) AS TOTAL, 
MONTHNAME(i.fecha) AS MES 
FROM 
impresiones i, usuarios u 
WHERE 
(u.usuario)='$idusuario' 
and (i.idempleado)=(u.idempleado) 
GROUP BY Mes");

while ($fila =mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
    echo $fila['TOTAL']."<br>";
    echo $fila['MES']."<br>";
}
```

en la variable consulta guardas la consulta a la base de datos y y con el while muestras los resultados con la funcion **mysqli_fetch_array**, me dices si te funciono o si me explique mal :).